# Split x into y parts of random numbers with a max value of n

Tags: javascript, math, mathematical-optimization

Can anyone provide a way to split a number into x amount of random parts with a max value?

I.e. 
    total number to be split = 50
    number of parts to split into = 10
    max val per part = 10

```
will return something like 
3,7,4,6,9,1,2,8,5,5
```

Each part is random to a degree. No uniform needed just y random numbers that add up to x with a maximum val per part.

I have found this already

```
var n = 16;
var a = [];
while (n > 0) {
 var s = Math.round(Math.random() * (n- 1)) + 1;

  a.push(s);
  n -= s;
}
console.log(a);
```

But this won't give x number of parts. It's a random number of parts...

Comment: you want 16 to be splitted into 10 parts and each part maximum value is 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var n = 16;
var a = [];
var parts = 10;
var maxValuePerPart = 10;

for(let i = 0; i < parts; i++){
 let max = (maxValuePerPart < n) ? maxValuePerPart : n;
 let min = 1;
 var s = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  a[i] = s;
  n -= s;
}

console.log(a);
```

Let me know if this is not what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

this is one way to do it. create an evenly devided array first to get the right ammount of "parts, and then loop trough it and for each "part" you add a random number to it while removing the same number from another random index.

```js
var n = 160;
var a = [];
var x = 10;
var b = n/x;

for(var i=0; i<x; i++){
  a.push(b);//create an array of 10 parts with the same value
}
for(var i=0; i<x; i++){
  var s = Math.round((Math.random()*b)) ;
  var index = Math.round((Math.random()*x))-1 ;
  a[i] += s;
  a[index] -=s;
}
console.log(a);
```

Comment: seems like hitting `unexpected identifier` exception